# Accessing a Folder that is not a wellknownfoldername nor inside of the Inbox

Tags: api, email, outlook, exchange-server

Using the exchange API, I am trying to access a folder within a folder within a folder. I am having trouble trying to access this folder since its root folder is not the inbox and I cannot use the wellknownname enum

Example of which folder I am trying to obtain

```
>inbox
 - Theses are folders in inbox
 - example folder in inbox 1
 - example folder in inbox 2

>special root folder (not inbox)
 - example folder in special root folder 1
 > this folder will hold the folder I need
    - folder in a folder in a folder example 1
    - *folder I need to acquire*
```

Comment: What code do you use for accessing folders?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev C#. I think i am able to use WellKnownFolderName.Root and then loop over until i find the outer most folder, then repeat until the desired folder is found.